# Sorry for dumb question but i need help making sense of this partial derivative

Tags: calculus, derivatives, computer-science

how could you take the value of x here when there is no $x$ value in the derived equation, again i apologize if the question seems extremely simple this has legit got me stumped...

[image]

Basically i want to know how the $7$-th equation can have $x$ values when there are none left in the derived equation since the partial derivative is taken with respect to $x$.

Comment: What do you mean?  The function $f(x)=|x|$ has derivative $1$ when $x>0$ and $-1$ when $x<0$.  The "$x$" is the argument of the derivative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect  you just misunderstood the statement:

They are not saying that $$\sum_n^H \sum_m^H U_{nm}^C  \max(0, 1-|y_i^s-n|) = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{if } |m-x_i^s| \geq 1 \\ 1 & \text{if }  m \geq x_i^s\\ -1 &\text{if }  m < x_i^S\end{cases}.$$

Rather, they intend to say:

$$V_i^C =  \sum_n^H \sum_m^H U_{nm}^C \max(0, 1-|x_i^s-m|) \max(0, 1-|y_i^s-n|)$$

$$\frac{\partial V_i^C}{\partial x_i^s} =  \sum_n^H \sum_m^H U_{nm}^C  \max(0, 1-|y_i^s-n|)\frac{\partial \max(0, 1-|x_i^s-m|)}{\partial x_i^S}$$

where

$$\frac{\partial \max(0, 1-|x_i^s-m|)}{\partial x_i^S} = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{if } |m-x_i^s| \geq 1 \\ 1 & \text{if } |m-x_i^s| < 1 \text{and } m \geq x_i^s\\ -1 &\text{if } |m-x_i^s| < 1 \text{and } m < x_i^S\end{cases}$$

Comment: I see thank you very much Siong, I failed to derive the derivative myself but you've been very helpful!

Comment: you are welcome. glad it helps.